# booth multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Is [booth algorithm for multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm) only for multiplying 2 negative numbers `(-3  * -4)` or one positive and one negative number `(-3 * 4)` ? Whenever i multiply 2 positive numbers using booth algorithm i get a wrong result.

example : 5 * 4

A = 101 000 0   `// binary of 5 is 101`

S = 011 000 0   `// 2's complement of 5 is 011`

P = 000 100 0   `// binary of 4 is 100`

x = 3

y = 3

m = 5

-m = 2's complement of m

r = 4

1. After right shift of P by 1 bit 0 000 100
2. After right shift of P by 1 bit 0 000 010
3. P+S = 011 001 0

   After right shift by 1 bit 0 011 001
4. Discarding the LSB 001100

   But that comes out to be the binary of 12 . It should have been 20(010100)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are using 3 bits for m and r, and they must be represented using 4 bits to get unsigned values.  (Using just 3 bits, 101 = -3 and 100 = -4, and the result does = 12).

So redoing this with 4 bits, one gets:

```
example : 5 * 4

A = 0101 0000 0 // binary of 5 is 0101

S = 1011 0000 0 // 2's complement of 5 is 1011

P = 0000 0100 0 // binary of 4 is 0100

x = 4

y = 4

m = 5

-m = 2's complement of m

r = 4

1.    After right shift of P by 1 bit 0000 0010 0

2.    After right shift of P by 1 bit 0000 0001 0

3.    P+S = 1011 0001 0

      After right shift by 1 bit 0101 1000 1

4.    P+A = 0010 1001 0     (not 1010 1001 0, since overflow in MSB is ignored)

      After right shift by 1 bit 0001 0100 1

Discarding the LSB gives 00010100   which is 20
```

which gives the correct answer.